# my scss is not overriding framework css UIkit

Tags: html, css, sass, getuikit

I'm having problems using scss to override framework css rules.
If I add `!important`, everything works fine... What should I do get this working without using that rule?
.html code:

```
<nav class="uk-navbar-container" uk-navbar>
    <div class="uk-navbar-left">

        <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
            <li class="uk-active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Parent</a>
                <div class="uk-navbar-dropdown">
                    <ul class="uk-nav uk-navbar-dropdown-nav">
                        <li class="uk-active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</nav>
```

.scss code:

```
.uk-navbar-container {
background: #383c4a;
}
```

Again, if I add `!important`, my navbar changes color...

Comment: You can always check applied styled for an element in devtools as well as why certain styles were overridden and by what. Most likely your styles are loaded before the framework and according to how css works the last rule is used.

Comment: I have a class on dev tools called `.uk-navbar-container:not(.uk-navbar-transparent)` that override my css rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that `.uk-navbar-container:not(.uk-navbar-transparent)` is more specific than your `.uk-navbar-container` rule. Another point is that normally you don't want to override framework's rules just for one fix, because it will affect your entire codebase.

One way to fix your issue is to add a more specific rule, e.g.

```
.uk-navbar-container.--grey {
    background: #383c4a;
}
```

... and then in html

```
<nav class="uk-navbar-container --grey" uk-navbar>
```

This will do the trick but only if the rule is defined **after** `.uk-navbar-container:not(.uk-navbar-transparent)`, because they have the same specificity and the last one will be applied. I attached a snipped to demonstrate how it works.

Read more about [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to get better understanding of the problem, and also you might want to check out [this article](https://bitsofco.de/on-not-and-specificity/) with examples with `not`.

```css
body {
  font-size: 22px;
}
.test:not(.another) {
  color: blue;
}
.test {
  color: red;
}
.test.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="test">I'm blue</div>
    <div class="test green">I'm green</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Many thanks, creating a new rule for that class worked fine! Thanks for all documentation you've sent aswell!